# How to aggregate a dataframe by week?

Tags: r, dplyr, xts, lubridate

Consider the following example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

time <- seq(from =ymd("2014-02-24"),to= ymd("2014-03-20"), by="days")
set.seed(123)
values <- sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = length(time), replace = TRUE)
df2 <- data_frame(time, values)
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(day_of_week = wday(time, label = TRUE))

Source: local data frame [25 x 3]

         time values day_of_week
       <date>  <dbl>      <fctr>
1  2014-02-24     30         Mon
2  2014-02-25     45        Tues
3  2014-02-26     30         Wed
4  2014-02-27     50       Thurs
5  2014-02-28     50         Fri
6  2014-03-01     20         Sat
7  2014-03-02     35         Sun
8  2014-03-03     50         Mon
9  2014-03-04     35        Tues
10 2014-03-05     35         Wed
```

I would like to aggregate this dataframe by week.

That is, suppose I define a week as starting on Monday morning and ending on Sunday evening, which we will call a `Monday to Monday` cycle. (importantly, I want to be able to choose other conventions, such as Friday to Friday for instance).

Then, I would simply like to count the mean of `values` for each week.

For instance, in the example above, one would compute the average of `values` between Monday February 24th to Sunday March 2nd, and so on.

How can I do that?

Comment: `df2 %>% group_by(week = week(time)) %>% summarise(value = mean(values))`, or use `isoweek` instead.

Comment: @Frank, done, thanks for the remark

Comment: @alistaire thanks for the suggestion, but your solution does not provide control over the week cycle. Say I want a Friday to Friday cycle here.

Comment: If the `week` function alistaire mentioned isn't exactly what you want, you can always sort the data and then `cumsum(day_of_week == "Mon")`. The result will break if you don't have every day recorded, though.

Comment: @Frank nice trick. I wonder if that could create some bad surprises (with duplicates?)

Comment: I was hoping for some canned solution from some package that allows the user to define its week cycles.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, duplicates could also be trouble. Could create an auxiliary table from min to max date, create the week var there and merge, but that might be a lot of trouble.

Comment: There's also `cut.Date`, which can do Sunday or Monday starts, if you like. Otherwise, you can add/subtract the appropriate number of days and use any of the options to shift the cut points.

Comment: @alistaire very interesting. do you have a link to the documentation? is it part of the base Date package?

Comment: Just `?cut.Date`, which takes you to `?cut.POSIXt`. Both are base methods for `cut`, which is part of base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this once, after some research, I actually think I came up with a better solution that

- gives the correct aggregation
- gives the correct labels

Example below for weeks starting on a **thursday**. The weeks will be labeled by their first day a given cycle.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
options(tibble.print_min = 30)

time <- seq(from =ymd("2014-02-24"),to= ymd("2014-03-20"), by="days")
set.seed(123)
values <- sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = length(time), replace = TRUE)
df2 <- data_frame(time, values)

df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(day_of_week_label = wday(time, label = TRUE),
                      day_of_week = wday(time, label = FALSE))

df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(thursday_cycle = time - ((as.integer(day_of_week) - 5) %% 7),
                      tmp_1 = (as.integer(day_of_week) - 5),
                      tmp_2 = ((as.integer(day_of_week) - 5) %% 7))
```

which gives

```
> df2
# A tibble: 25 × 7
         time values day_of_week_label day_of_week thursday_cycle tmp_1 tmp_2
       <date>  <dbl>             <ord>       <dbl>         <date> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2014-02-24     30               Mon           2     2014-02-20    -3     4
2  2014-02-25     45              Tues           3     2014-02-20    -2     5
3  2014-02-26     30               Wed           4     2014-02-20    -1     6
4  2014-02-27     50             Thurs           5     2014-02-27     0     0
5  2014-02-28     50               Fri           6     2014-02-27     1     1
6  2014-03-01     20               Sat           7     2014-02-27     2     2
7  2014-03-02     35               Sun           1     2014-02-27    -4     3
8  2014-03-03     50               Mon           2     2014-02-27    -3     4
9  2014-03-04     35              Tues           3     2014-02-27    -2     5
10 2014-03-05     35               Wed           4     2014-02-27    -1     6
11 2014-03-06     50             Thurs           5     2014-03-06     0     0
12 2014-03-07     35               Fri           6     2014-03-06     1     1
13 2014-03-08     40               Sat           7     2014-03-06     2     2
14 2014-03-09     40               Sun           1     2014-03-06    -4     3
15 2014-03-10     20               Mon           2     2014-03-06    -3     4
16 2014-03-11     50              Tues           3     2014-03-06    -2     5
17 2014-03-12     25               Wed           4     2014-03-06    -1     6
18 2014-03-13     20             Thurs           5     2014-03-13     0     0
19 2014-03-14     30               Fri           6     2014-03-13     1     1
20 2014-03-15     50               Sat           7     2014-03-13     2     2
21 2014-03-16     50               Sun           1     2014-03-13    -4     3
22 2014-03-17     40               Mon           2     2014-03-13    -3     4
23 2014-03-18     40              Tues           3     2014-03-13    -2     5
24 2014-03-19     50               Wed           4     2014-03-13    -1     6
25 2014-03-20     40             Thurs           5     2014-03-20     0     0
```

Answer (score 48):

In the tidyverse,

```
df2 %>% group_by(week = week(time)) %>% summarise(value = mean(values))

## # A tibble: 5 × 2
##    week    value
##   <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1     8 37.50000
## 2     9 38.57143
## 3    10 38.57143
## 4    11 36.42857
## 5    12 45.00000
```

Or use `isoweek` instead:

```
df2 %>% group_by(week = isoweek(time)) %>% summarise(value = mean(values))

## # A tibble: 4 × 2
##    week    value
##   <int>    <dbl>
## 1     9 37.14286
## 2    10 40.71429
## 3    11 35.00000
## 4    12 42.50000
```

Or `cut.Date`:

```
df2 %>% group_by(week = cut(time, "week")) %>% summarise(value = mean(values))

## # A tibble: 4 × 2
##         week    value
##       <fctr>    <dbl>
## 1 2014-02-24 37.14286
## 2 2014-03-03 40.71429
## 3 2014-03-10 35.00000
## 4 2014-03-17 42.50000
```

which you can tell to start on Sunday, if you prefer:

```
df2 %>% group_by(week = cut(time, "week", start.on.monday = FALSE)) %>% 
    summarise(value = mean(values))

## # A tibble: 4 × 2
##         week    value
##       <fctr>    <dbl>
## 1 2014-02-23 37.50000
## 2 2014-03-02 40.00000
## 3 2014-03-09 33.57143
## 4 2014-03-16 44.00000
```

If you want to shift to, say, Tuesday start, add one to your dates:

```
df2 %>% group_by(week = cut(time + 1, "week")) %>% summarise(value = mean(values))

## # A tibble: 4 × 2
##         week    value
##       <fctr>    <dbl>
## 1 2014-02-24 37.50000
## 2 2014-03-03 40.00000
## 3 2014-03-10 33.57143
## 4 2014-03-17 44.00000
```

Labels will be off, though. If using `cut`, consider the implications of its `include.lowest` and `right` parameters, documented at `?cut`.

Answer (score 10):

why not straight up use `floor_date` and an integer to adjust the start date of the week?

```
library(lubridate)
time <- seq(from =ymd("2014-02-24"),to= ymd("2014-03-20"), by="days")

set.seed(123)

values <- sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = length(time), replace = TRUE)  
df2 <- data_frame(time, values)
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(day_of_week = weekdays(time))

# week wednesday to tuesday
df2 %>% group_by(Week = floor_date(time-3, unit="week")) %>% 
  summarize(WeeklyAveDist=mean(values), mean(values), min_date = min(time), max_date = max(time)) %>% mutate(weekdays(min_date), weekdays(max_date)))

        Week WeeklyAveDist mean.values.   min_date   max_date
1 2014-02-16      37.50000     37.50000 2014-02-24 2014-02-25
2 2014-02-23      38.57143     38.57143 2014-02-26 2014-03-04
3 2014-03-02      38.57143     38.57143 2014-03-05 2014-03-11
4 2014-03-09      36.42857     36.42857 2014-03-12 2014-03-18
5 2014-03-16      45.00000     45.00000 2014-03-19 2014-03-20
  weekdays.min_date. weekdays.max_date.
1             Monday            Tuesday
2          Wednesday            Tuesday
3          Wednesday            Tuesday
4          Wednesday            Tuesday
5          Wednesday           Thursday


# Week Thursday to Wednesday
df2 %>% group_by(Week = floor_date(time-4, unit="week")) %>% 
  summarize(WeeklyAveDist=mean(values), mean(values), min_date = min(time), max_date = max(time)) %>% mutate(weekdays(min_date), weekdays(max_date)))

        Week WeeklyAveDist mean.values.   min_date   max_date
1 2014-02-16      35.00000     35.00000 2014-02-24 2014-02-26
2 2014-02-23      39.28571     39.28571 2014-02-27 2014-03-05
3 2014-03-02      37.14286     37.14286 2014-03-06 2014-03-12
4 2014-03-09      40.00000     40.00000 2014-03-13 2014-03-19
5 2014-03-16      40.00000     40.00000 2014-03-20 2014-03-20
  weekdays.min_date. weekdays.max_date.
1             Monday          Wednesday
2           Thursday          Wednesday
3           Thursday          Wednesday
4           Thursday          Wednesday
5           Thursday           Thursday
```

Comment: this might be the cleanest one.

Comment: just to be sure, can you just explain what `floor_date(time-4, unit="week")` does?

Comment: From documentation, page 50 : "floor_date takes a date-time object and rounds it down to the nearest boundary of the specified
time unit". https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf

Comment: thanks! but I dont understand how using it with time minus n solves the question

Comment: it subtracts the integer value of days from the date before aggregating to a week . Try any `POSIXct` / `date` class object minus integer value and see results.

Comment: thanks @vagabond I get that, but I dont understand why subtracting 3 to the current data and feeding it to `floor_date` gives wednesday to tuesday groups.

Answer (score 2):

```
aggregate(df2$values,by=list(week(df2$time)),mean)
```

> ```
>   Group.1        x
> 1       8 30.00000
> 2       9 40.00000
> 3      10 36.42857
> 4      11 37.85714
> 5      12 43.33333
> ```

This uses the `week` function of lubridate and gives the week number of the week in the year.

To control which day of the week is the starting day just refer to this thread on that topic:

[Changing lubridate function to start on Monday rather than Sunday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160117/changing-lubridate-function-to-start-on-monday-rather-than-sunday)

The solution from that thread by nograpes suggests that if you want a custom version of the `week()` function using an arbitrary day of the week as the beginning of the week that you just construct it from base R like this:

> ```
> start.of.week <- function(date)
>   date - (setNames(c(6,0:5),0:6) [strftime(date,'%w')])
>
> end.of.week <- function(date)
>   date + (setNames(c(0,6:1),0:6) [strftime(date,'%w')])
>
> start.of.week(as.Date(c('2014-01-05','2014-10-02','2014-09-22','2014-09-27')))
> # "2013-12-30" "2014-09-29" "2014-09-22" "2014-09-22"
> end.of.week(as.Date(c('2014-01-05','2014-10-02','2014-09-22','2014-09-27')))
> # "2014-01-05" "2014-10-05" "2014-09-28" "2014-09-28"
> ```

In the future `lubridate` will have this option for an arbitrary start day for weeks, but Hadley hasn't got around to adding it yet (https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/257).

Comment: thanks @Hack-R but your solution does not provide control over the week-cycles. Also, its impossible to know which week we are into by looking at the group labels

Comment: @Noobie It's the week cycle that you requested in your question. It's the week number of the week in the year. How did you want the week to be labeled?

Comment: Ok thanks. The label is not important, as I can always concatenate the year-week number. However, imagine I prefer a Friday to Friday cycle. How can I adapt your solution then?

Comment: thanks @Hack-R, super useful. However, do you mind quickly explaining what is going on here? I dont understand what the function is doing...

Comment: the `Date - (setNames(c(6,0:5),0:6) [strftime(date,'%w')])` part I mean

Comment: I just dont understand the syntax here