# How to summarise weakly mean of daily data in R

Tags: r, date

I want to have the average daily_mean_score per week. I have summarised the data per day already (which is how i got daily_mean_score). So, now I want to know per week what the average score is. However, I am doing an observational study, so I dont want to weeks to end at 52/53, but to continue till there is no more data left (e.g. last week is week 180). Subsequently I will be able to plot the trend in weeks over the years.

This is the data frame:

https://prnt.sc/p7gzru

Comment: To improve your chances of getting an answer, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post. In particular, including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question is essential.

Comment: did you see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554231/dplyr-lubridate-how-to-aggregate-a-dataframe-by-week/40554522)?